# oc rollout fails from command line, while working from the web console. How to investigate?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

After weeks of being fine, the deployment stopped working and results in the message:

```
"Error from server (BadRequest): cannot trigger a deployment for "xxxx" because it contains unresolved images"
```

This is an in-premises Openshift 3.5 cluster, the very same deployment works just fine from the web console. "oc get events" does not return anything, raising loglevel did not help me either. Can it be related to network setup? DNS, firewall - these are the only changes in the meantime I am aware of, but I would like to know how to investigate it from openshift perspective.

Comment: Do an ``oc get -o yaml`` on the deployment config. Find out what images it is referencing. Use ``oc get is`` to see if those image streams still exist. Likely someone deleted the image stream it was referencing.

Comment: Thanks Graham, that was my first line of thinking. The images seem to be fine, as I said - the dc works from the web console. I'm suspecting differences between nodes, but not sure how to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late update - turned out that it was one of the nodes having connectivity problems with the registry. Incidentally when run from web console, the builder pod got assigned to a working node, when from cmd - to the failing one. Investigating the builds helped.